# How to execute parallel 'for' loop containing if statements

Tags: bash, for-loop, parallel-processing

I've this function for processing some images and converting it to pdf. Question is: how to run the for loop in this function in parallel to process the files more quickly?

```bash
pdf_compile() {
  start=`date +%s.%N`
  tmpdir=".temp"
  if [ ! -d "$tmpdir" ]; then
    mkdir $tmpdir
  fi
  echo "width: $1px"
  [[ -z $2 ]] && filter="sc1" || filter="$2" 
  echo "filter:" $filter
  count=$(ls | grep .jpg | wc -l)
  dn=1
  for f in *.jpg ; do
    nm="$tmpdir/$1-$filter-$f"
    if [ ! -f "$nm" ]; then
      echo "processing $f ($dn/$count)"
      if [[ "$filter" =~ ^sc1 ]]; then
        convert $f -resize $1x \
        -brightness-contrast 21x33 \
        -enhance -despeckle -sharpen 2 $nm
      elif [[ "$filter" =~ ^sc2 ]]; then
        convert $f -resize $1x \
          -brightness-contrast 19x45 \
          -sharpen 1 -despeckle -despeckle \
          -enhance $nm
      elif [[ "$filter" =~ ^sc3 ]]; then
        convert -resize $1x \
          -brightness-contrast 19x35 \
          -sharpen 1 -enhance -despeckle \
          -gamma 1.05 \
          -brightness-contrast -30x90 \
          -enhance $nm
      fi
      ffmpeg -i $nm $nm -y -hide_banner -loglevel error
    else
      echo "using cached $f ($dn/$count)"
    fi
    ((dn++))
  done
  n="$(basename $PWD)_$1px.pdf"
  echo "\nconverting to pdf"
  convert $tmpdir/$1-$filter-*.jpg $n
    if [[ "$3" =~ ^y ]]; then
      echo "removing temp"
      rm $tmpdir -r
    fi
  end=`date +%s.%N`
  runtime=$( echo "$end - $start" | bc -l )
  echo "completed in" $runtime "s"
}
```

I tired this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/216475

```bash
for f in *.jpg ; do
    ((i=i%N)); ((i++==0)) && wait
       .......
done
```

But it didn't improve the processing time

Comment: I suggest you write a script that processes one file then use`xargs -P` or (gnu) `parallel` to run said script in parallel.  You end up with easy to maintain code, and you externalize how parallel you want to run it.

Comment: GNU `make` is another option. It has parallel processing capabilities, plus it manages the dependencies between input files and output files such that it does not redo things that are up to date. If you want to improve performance this second characteristic is maybe interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is incomplete and has quite a few issues. Try pasting it into https://shellcheck.net for some guidance.

You could put `&` at the end of each of the 3 `convert` statements inside the `if` statements in the `for` loop to do them all in the background and then add `wait` before the final `convert` that creates the PDF.

```
for ...
   if ...
      convert ... &
   else ...
      convert ... &
   else ...
      convert ... &
done
...
wait    # for all JPEGs to finish
convert ... XXX.PDF
```

Rather than create intermediate JPEGs on disk, you could maybe create *"Magick Pixel Cache"* files by changing the extension to `.mpc` and see if that is faster. You could also write them to a RAM-based filesystem like `/tmp` instead of the local, presumably disk-based filesystem.

You give no indication of the image sizes. If you start with multi-thousand pixel wide images and go to several hundred pixels width, you could usefully use *"shrink-on-load"* feature.

You give little indication of how many pages your PDFs have, nor how long each part of the processing takes. Better specified questions are often easier to answer well...

Comment: What works incredible well in practice is using multiple directories.  todo, in-progress, and done.  move is atomic so it will only work for one process, in-process, if process dies (or killed) can be found here (easy to mv back to todo), and done is the processed input files (and output if you want).

Comment: Thanks! This solution works well. @AllanWind's solution also works. Both have nearly same efficiency in my case (just a dozen pages of about 4000px size)